# Преобразование DTO в сущность: где это лучше делать?

Tags: java

Итак, классическая архитектура веб-приложения. Контроллер, сервис, маппер (который мапит dto в сущность и обратно). В каком-то слое нужно заавтовайрить маппер и преобразовывать dto в сущность и обратно. Есть два подхода.

1. Преобразование в контроллере. Таким образом, сервис принимает уже сущность со всеми зависимостями и возвращает сущность (которая опять преобразовывается в контроллере в dto и отправляется, скажем, на фронт). За этот подход то соображение, что dto является данными, полученными извне, а значит, он должен быть преобразован в сущность как можно раньше и уйти в другие слои уже в виде сущности. Также, за этот подход выступают те частые случаи, когда нам нужно получить сущность А в сервисе Б. Тогда в сервисе Б мы автовайрим сервис А, идём в сервис А по ID сущности и получаем сущность, но сервис отдаёт dto, и вот он преобразовывает полученную сущность в dto, который возвращается в сервис Б и там происходит обратная трансформация dto в сущность, с заполнением зависимостей и походами в базу. Или же нам приходится писать второй какой-нибудь метод `public Car get(Long id)` в дополнение к `public CarDto get(Long id)`. Что тоже не упрощает код.
2. Преобразование в сервисе. Этот подход подразумевает применение сущности только для работы с репозиторием. Плюс подхода в том, что dto намного легче сущности в плане зависимостей, и гонять его между сервисами намного проще, да и работать с dto намного проще. Не надо задумываться о консистентности данных, lazy initialization и прочих тонкостях работы с сущностями. Так же, это позволяет контролировать все запросы в базу, если нам потребовалась зависимость, мы просто берём её по данным dto, избегая, таким образом, случаев, когда для получения int-поля приходится тянуть из базы всю сущность с деревом зависимостей и хранить это в памяти.

Итак, джентльмены, хочется услышать ваш голос на этот счёт.

Comment: Ваш вопрос изначально некорректный. DTO - это Data Transfer Object - то есть где вам надо данные передать объектами, там и конвертируйте. Если вам это надо делать в сервисе - делайте в сервисе. Если вам это надо в контроллере - делайте в контроллере.

Comment: Жаль, что многие комментаторы не читают вопросы дальше заголовка...

Comment: К чему это? Вы хотите меня как то лично охарактеризовать? Я прочитал ваш вопрос и отписал то, что думаю по этому поводу - не это ли вы просили? Если вам мой комментарий не нравится - это не значит, что я отнесся к вашему вопросу безответсвенно. Если вы хотите меня попросить что то дополнить или пояснить - то это говорите, а ваша характеристика, что я прочитал, а что нет, не просто неверна, но и не добавляет никакой пользы ни вам, ни мне.

Comment: Не вижу смысла продолжать эту дискуссию лично с Вами.

Comment: Без проблем, удачи с вопросом.

Comment: я за второй подход, поскольку это разграничивает/изолирует (условно скажем слои - контролер, сервис) слои, что делает их менее связанными архитектурно, легче тестируемыми и т.д.

Comment: Я тоже за 2. Но коллеги категорически за 1. Поэтому опять поиском вернулся к этому же вопросу. Спасибо автору!
Странно что слои  одинаковые, но основные преобразования делаются в разных слоях. И странно что отозвавшихся мало. Неужели до сих пор нет строгой теории по этому вопросу?
И ещё интересно: есть статистика по соотношению 1 и 2 вариантов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, что лучше всего преобразовывать отдельно от всех слоёв: в  преобразователях за пределами слоёв. А преобразование вызывать точно не в контроллере. [Здесь хорошая схема на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44885988/2085768)